# how to connect Keycloak image in docker to external oracle DB

Tags: linux, database, oracle, docker, keycloak

I am trying to connect my keycloak image in docker with external database which is already running on linux server. I am trying this script:`docker run -p "9000:9000" -e DB_VENDOR=oracle -e DB_ADDR=192.168.248.111 -e DB_PORT=1521 -e DB_USER=abc -e DB_PASSWORD=abc -e DB_DATABASE=xe -e KEYCLOAK_USERNAME=admin -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=pass jboss/keycloak`

Can anyone please help me with that?

Comment: what error are you getting ? you need to provide more details

Comment: any update on this?